# f# Insert on MongoDB using Records

Tags: mongodb, f#

I've been trying for a while to insert on MongoDB using only records with no success.

My problem is that I want to create a simple insert function which I send a generic type and it is inserted into the database.

Like so.

```
let insert (value: 'a) = 
    let collection = MongoClient().GetDatabase("db").GetCollection<'a> "col"
    collection.InsertOne value
```

From this function, I tried inserting the following records.

```
// Error that it can't set the Id
type t1 = {
    Id: ObjectId
    Text: string
}
// Creates the record perfectly but doesn't generate a new Id
type t2 = {
    Id: string
    Text: string
}
// Creates the record and autogenerates the Id but doesn't insert the Text, and there are two Ids (_id, Id@) 
type t3 = {
    mutable Id: ObjectId
    Text: string
}
// Creates the record and autogenerates the Id but for every property it generates two on MongoDB (_id, Id@, Text, Text@)
type t4 = {
    mutable Id: ObjectId
    mutable Text: string
}
```

So does anyone can think of a solution for this or am I stuck having to use a class.

```
// Works!!!
type t5() = 
    member val Id = ObjectId.Empty with get, set
    member val Name = ""  with get, set
```

Also, does anyone has any Idea of why when the C# MongoDB library translates the mutable he gets the property with the @ at the end?
I would be fine with having all my properties set as mutable, although this wouldn't be my first choice, having he create multiple properties on the DB is quite bad.

Comment: Which driver are you using? The .NET driver? Kind of confusing what you are asking here, and trying to work out if you are trying to have an `ObjectId` value automatically assigned to a field stored as `"Id"` or if you just mean `"_id"` which would be automatically added anyway.

Comment: I am using the default MongoDB C# Driver. https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/
I meant the "_id" It should be automatically added, but it is not if you use records, Wich I do get since there is no set if he just changes the value before inserting on the database this makes a lot of sense, it is the wrong way of doing imo it since if you use records it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You could try annotating your records with [`CLIMutable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.climutableattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D) (and no `mutable` fields).

The `@`s end up in the DB because MongoDB using reflection and F# implementing `mutable` with backing fields `fieldName@`

Comment: I thought that using CLIMutable would be the same as having all my properties set as mutable, it turns out it is not. 
Still it doesn't work on my case the MongoDB driver leaves the ID null.
I am trully sailing uncharted waters here since i don't see any other f# developer facing the same problems that I have. 
Guess everyone just does what I am doing now, using classes that works very well when interfacing with the C# library.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like this blog post shows how https://medium.com/@mukund.sharma92/cruding-in-f-with-mongodb-e4699d1ac17e